# how to direct a website upon click of a hyperlink button in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I want to add a hyperlink button in my silverlight website and upon click of the hyperlink button it will direct to the website binded on it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<HyperlinkButton Content="Click Me" NavigateUri="http://www.google.com">
```